# Will Undervoltage Damage A Brushless Fan?

Tags: solar-cell, brushless-dc-motor, fan, 24v, undervoltage

I have an off-grid solar panel set up ready and it works really well. My solar PWM charge controller of the back side aluminum heat sink is too hot to touch when its during sunlight.
I was thinking about using a brushless fan for cooling the heat sink. I checked the voltage of the panel and its about 19.4v when peak. So it should be good to use a 24v fan since I don't need full speed and that the adequate fan will cool the heatsink during the daytime. I did not use 24 hours running the fan since the heatsink is not hot during night so I don't think I need battery backup.

The question is that if during dusk/evening then will the undervolted fan might struggle got damaged? I know that regular fan/motors will damage but will a brushless fan damage since they have electronics and may have a cut off or something? The brushless fan I'm using a regular Chinese 60mm brushless fan used for computer chassis.

Edit: Will a diagram like this work?

[image]

Comment: Probably depends on whether the fan has voltage cutoff circuitry or not. Test with a variable supply to see when the fan stops running (and when it stops starting up, which may not be the same). You might also be able to finagle something using the third control pin on the fan.

Comment: Alright I can test it with a variable supply but how can I know if the fan has stalled or stopped?

Comment: With your eyes.

Comment: @Kokachi As for ``how can I know if the fan has stalled or stopped`` some fans have a _Tachometer Signal_ output, which can be used to measure the fan rotation speed, or detect if the rotor has locked. Have you a particular 24 V fan in mind?

Comment: What does the fan's data sheet say about supply voltage range?

Comment: Just put a low-voltage disconnect on it and don't worry?

Comment: @ChesterGillon The fan I use are generic either oiled containing or a ball bearing Chinese fans with just 2 wires so no signal from the third wire. Usually the names like Sunon or Pengda like such and poor without available datasheets.

Comment: @hobbs  Please show me how to do that?

Comment: @Kokachi you buy it, you connect the + to the + and the - to the -.

Comment: Will a 1N4744A zener diode in series before a fan cut-off at 15 volts? fan uses 0.2 watts at 24v

Comment: If using cheap chinese fans with limited docs, buy an extra and test the heck out of the spare